# Proper tearDown Hibernate testing with H2

Tags: hibernate, jpa, tdd, jpa-2.0, h2

Currently I am using the below after every test I have in my test suite. However it makes it very slow because H2 has to reload the application context after every test.  Is there a quicker way to clear all my objects so I do not have carry over between tests?

```
@org.junit.After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    context.close();
}
```

Comment: why aren't you just rolling back the transaction at the end of each test? something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618914/spring-integration-test-does-not-roll-back

Comment: If the A was good for you, could you accept it? Changes status from open. Thx

Comment: would be nice to see the import/instantiation of `context`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try **`context.clear()`**

EntityManager.clear:  Clear the persistence context, causing all managed entities to become detached. Changes made to entities that have not been flushed to the database will not be persisted.

Session.clear: Completely clear the session.

Also, you can ensure the entity manager / session used in each test is identical by implementing a singleton pattern.  And you can use a dynamic SQL script to clear data from all tables.  Both described under PersistenceHelper [here](http://www.objectpartners.com/2010/11/09/unit-testing-your-persistence-tier-code).

Comment: Glen, sorry for taking so long, this did take care of the issue.